# CSS hr dashed is displaying wrong

Tags: html, css

I made a dashed line in CSS and rendered it in HTML with extra arguments. But when the line it self rendered it cut off bits at start and end.

```
hr.vertical {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    border: dashed;
    -webkit-animation: circlein 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: circlein 1s;
}
```

Rendered: http://gyazo.com/f3b1a25759017bd7b4dba789d34bffc9

Comment: you want it to be like so ? http://jsfiddle.net/nnx8xn8w/1/

Comment: It is suppose to not be random size per dash. I want it so all dashes are same size